# EasyHook library use

Tags: c#, dll-injection, setwindowshookex, easyhook, api-hook

I looked at the EasyHook and their tutorial samples and even implemented LocalHook with my own API from advapi32.dll, the LocalHook worked when I was making calls from the same app where my hooking code was running, but no interception occurred when I was calling the hooked API from another external process. I guess I was wrong about my assumption about interception from external process.

So now I am looking at the RemoteHook and my impression is that you need to specifically build your injection DLL and inject it into a known process/executable - this, however, is not my goal/scenario. The goal was to intercept a call to API that lives in advapi32.dll regardless of the process that makes the call - that is, from any (unknown) process. This is something, I believe, is called GlobalHook. So, is it possible to write GlobalHook in a way that from my GUI app will intercept a call of any process to specific API in specific Win32 DLL, or .NET DLL such as system.security.cryptography.algorithms.dll (and how do I know in general, what Win32 APIs are being used by this DLL (if at all)? Or should I switch to MS Detour library for Global hook implementation? Is Global Hook implemented with SetWindowsHookEx triggers anti-virus programs?

Comment: The only reliable way to Dll inject is to start from the kernel create a driver, hook CreateProcess and LoadLibrary, etc, check for the dll, inject, jump into the address space, and override the jumps to proxy to the dll.  Even then this gets sketchy. There are products that create such drivers for you, however these companies are careful who they deal with as this is the first things kids try to do to write viruses and they don't want their drivers blacklisted. Secondly, even if you have such a product, virus detectors take a dim view of this. Also none of this can be done in C#

Comment: If  you are wanting a reliable hooking solution, this is for commercial purposes or line of business apps, you are handy with C++, and don't mind getting your hands dirty, I believe there is a company call Madshi, with a product called MadCodeHook, Do note its been a while since I have needed to do this professionally, and not sure what else is on the market

Comment: OK, so this answer, although could be true, is not what I expected. At this point I do not want to go kernel level driver way, that is File System Filter Driver. I consider this as a last resort. My main concern is to know whether global hook will be flagged by antivirus. I contemplate a product that will prevent special kind of viruses/malware.... by all means not another antivirus though...